# Pandoc - from MD to PDF - Undefined control sequence error

Tags: pdf, pandoc, markdown

As a beginner, I've just installed MikTex and Pandoc.
I'm trying to convert my markdown file into a pdf file using pandoc, but pandoc returns an error which goes like this:

```
    Error producing PDF.
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.132 ...}}^\alpha}{{k_t^*}^{\alpha}}-1\xlongequal
```

The corresponding content in my markdown file is:

```
(2) $\Rightarrow$ The growth rate of $\frac{Y}{AN}$ is
$$
\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_t}-1=\frac{{k_{t+1}^{*}}^\alpha}{{k_t^*}^{\alpha}}-1\xlongequal{steady\space{}state}\frac{k_t^{*\alpha{}}}{k_t^{*\alpha{}}}-1=0
$$
```

It looks fine in Typora:
[image]

Could anyone help me on this issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: What is `\xlongequal`?

Comment: Hi @Mensch , thanks for your reply! I've added a screenshot in my question - I think it works well in Typora, but I don't know how to rewrite it to make it compilable with Pandoc. 

Comment: You need the `extarrows` package for `\xlongequal` to be defined